# how to display data from mysql, on tables that have been created in the .html file

Tags: php, html

I am confused how to display data that has been entered into mysql by
via **file.php** to be displayed into the existing table in **file.html**

**here is the code .html** :

```
<form class="formnya" action="../php/newcustomer.php"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table class="form_new_customer">
    <tr>
                <th colspan="2"><h3 align="center"><u>Customer Baru</u></h3></th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Nama Lengkap:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nama_lengkap"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Jenis Kelamin:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Pria">Pria
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Wanita">Wanita
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Nama Toko:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nama_toko"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="alamat">Alamat:</td>
                <td><textarea rows="5" cols="21" name="alamat"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>No.Hp/Telp :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="no_hp"></td>
            </tr>

            <!-- <tr>
                <td>Foto KTP: </td>
                <td><input type="file" name="files"></td>
            </tr> -->

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn1"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

**and below is my .php file**

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    include_once 'connect.php';

    $nama_lengkap = $_POST['nama_lengkap'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $nama_toko = $_POST['nama_toko'];
    $alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
    $no_hp = $_POST['no_hp'];
    // $files = $_FILES['files'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO user ('nama_lengkap','jenis_kelamin','nama_toko','alamat','no_handphone')
            VALUES ('$nama_lengkap','$gender','$nama_toko','$alamat','$no_hp')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    header("Location: ../pages/newcustomer.html?=success");
}
```

?>

so my question is, may i used the file .html to show the data from .php?

Comment: Please read about SQL injection before doing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ajax (use another PHP file) to load data from database and then display in your HTML file.

But, you can also convert your .html file to .php file in order to get data from MySQL directly.

For Ajax based data, please refer to this example:
https://www.w3schools.com/pHP/php_ajax_php.asp

From the ajax URL (a PHP file), you can return data in JSON format or a complete HTML based table. Better is to return JSON based data, then parse the data in your JavaScript code and insert the data in your HTML table in code.html

PS: You can call Ajax function on document/body onload event like:

```
<head>
    <script>
    function getData() {
        // Your ajax code here (URL given above for example code)
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="getData()">
...
</body>
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, i really new in php, and just get confused to use what extention to show data from mysql